# How to do docker build image from dockerfile on Kubernetes 1.20

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes

Kubernetes 1.20 moved from docker to CRI-O as container runtime. I have a scenario where my Jenkins run on kubernetes and does docker build my dockerfile .But the build breaks as docker daemon is not available now.
I tried using Kaniko to build image but the downfall was once image is built i have no chance to scan the image before pushing to container registry. Once the image is built i have to push it immediately. How can i scan it before pushing to registry.

Current process:

1. Jenkins runs on Kubernetes.
2. Pulls code and does the docker build and tag it.
3. Once docker build is successful will a scan the image for vulnerabilities.
4. Once scan passes we push to the container registry.

With Kaniko i can do till step 2 later image goes away I am not able to find the image locally but i can push directly. And pull it and do scan. Any suggestions or alternatives so i can use my old dockerfiles build,scan and push without major changes

Comment: What was your solution to this? I'm in the same situation now

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at [podman](http://docs.podman.io/en/latest/index.html), is like run docker but without the need of a daemon.

You can also check [buildah](https://github.com/containers/buildah/blob/main/README.md)

Comment: Thanks for the answer,  I tried podman but only con was it doesn't support cache. That makes build slower.